# Online form with ability to remember certain fields

Tags: forms

I am searching for a service which lets me make a form in which i would be able to let it remember certain fields.

[image: What i have now]
The idea would be that next to "klaar" (done) there would be a button "nog een versie" (another version)
When clicked it should remember: Ordernummer, Order, Per Omwenteling

So far i haven't found a service that can provide me with these specific needs.

Iff there is no service with these capabilities would it be possible to code this with an htlm form?

Greeting,
Antony

Answer (score 0):

Would you like your form to remember the last inputted Ordernummer, Order, Per Omwenteling? If yes I suggest using php and mysql to run a query and return the latest values of these fields. This can be embedded in your html